# how to remove first 5 or 7 characters using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have posted the a question using the given javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showData($sel){
        var str='';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        for (var i=0;i<sel.options.length;i++){
            str+=(str!='') ? ', '+sel.options[i].value : sel.options[i].value;
        }
    }
    sel.form.selectedFruits.value = str;
</script>
```

now the question is that how to remove first 5 or 7 using this javascript. please help by setting in this javascript.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of removing, think of grabbing what you need from the string.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.  You want to remove the first 5 or 7 (characters presumably from the title) from what?  And how should we determine whether to remove 5 or 7, randomly?

Comment: `how to remove first 5 or 7 using this javascript` Step1: delete this script, it does you no good. Step 2: decide if 5 or 7 chars to remove. Step 3: start coding. Step 4: happy!

Comment: [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: what is the condition for removing 5 vs 7?

Comment: Just fyi, just checked out your other questions. The code on this and the one for removing numbers is the exact same, you're not giving us anything "viable" to work with. Also, **you have been given some great answers on almost all your questions, you need to check mark those answers to get your rep up and show people you're worth answering for, else you won't last long on here as people will stop answering your questions**

Comment: And another thing, as I look through your questions I notice you constantly mix jQuery with Vanilla JS. This is not good. You really need to go read jQuery Documentation and learn it, or stick with Vanilla JS. One of the key points of jQuery is to eliminate the *long* lines of vanilla JS you keep writing. You're obviously very green, so please take this advice as *constructive criticism* and get a handle on what you're doing before you ask any more questions.

Comment: thanks for your siggessions. i will keep in mind next time

Comment: Not a problem. Though it might look mean, I meant no offense, simply trying to help you get your footing in here and realize what kind of mistakes you're making before someone rubs you the wrong way and you just give up. This is a great sight for answers and jQuery is the best thing to JS since the internet, but if you're going to use em, try to use em right. Keep up the learning!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could follow the [`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) suggestion given by [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403485/how-to-remove-first-5-or-7-characters-using-javascript#answer-18403554), but more often than not, to remove characters in JS you use the [`slice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) method.  For example, if you have:

```
var str="Hello world!";
```

Removing the first 5 characters is as easy as:

```
var n=str.slice(5);
```

You parameters are very simple. The first is where to start, in this case, position 5. The second is how far to go based on original string character length, in this case, nothing since we want to go to the end of the string. The result would be:

```
" world!"
```

To remove the first 7 characters would be as easy as:

```
var n=str.slice(7);
```

And the result would be:

```
"orld!"
```

|OR| if you wanted to GET the 5th to 7th character, you would use something like:

```
var n=str.slice(4, 7);
```

The reson being that it *starts* at position 4 meaning the first character grabbed is the 5th character. Whereas the second parameter is what character to stop at, thus use of "7". This will stop it at the 7th character thus producing:

```
"o w"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i mixed part of your suggested code with mine and it got worked......

Answer (score 8):

You can use `substr` with 1 parameter. This will cut the first `x` characters from the string and return the remaining.

```
var foo = '12345String starts here';
alert(foo.substr(5)); // = "String starts here"
```

How you determine where to cut the string is up to you, as your question does not include enough detail.

Comment: `var split = [5, 7]; var value = split[Math.floor(Math.random()*split.length)]; var foo = '12345String starts here'; alert(foo.substr(value));` Just for the joke...

Comment: sry rory, after having looked thru his profile and other questions, I think our answers and advice fall upon "def" ears. nice answer tho, I included you in mine and give ya props, since the op might not ever pick an answer.

Comment: sorry actually i can choose one answer and even i cant vote up next time when i will be having the reputation upto requirements i will be doing that. even i tried before to give vote but i cant sorry again if it hurts or produce any type of disappoinmtment

Comment: @usman610 nah, I was worried for a moment when I started glancing your profile, but I noticed you took my advice to heart and immediately started making changes of improvement. All any "teacher" ever ask is to be "listened" too and you're doing just that! Welcome to SO and hope you continue to come back a lot and learn and grow. As I mentioned before, you should really study jQuery more as it will begin to replace all your JavaScript with a few exceptions, such as these 2 answers. Again, welcome to the community and thanks for going back and selecting answers. It really helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In both **JavaScript** and **Java** :), the same syntax:

`"stackoverflow".substring(5); // will return "overflow"`