# Remove first 10 characters from document.title

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

How would I write a custom Javascript variable in Google tag manager to remove the first 10 letters/characters of the document.title that is currently in place?

The first 10 characters are always the same and clutter up what I'm trying to do. Removing the characters would be useful, and I know it can be done, just not sure how to structure the slice.

Comment: @HereticMonkey your answer is for c# not javascript

Comment: [how to remove first 5 or 7 characters using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18403485/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring function

```js
const s = "123456789-STRING".substring(10,);
console.log(s)
```

Comment: You don't need that comma in the substring function. It doesn't look very well. But it works fine without it. Also, you gave a pure JS answer. the author won't be able to use it in GTM. You need to make it an anonymous function. starting with `function(){` returning your s. Using title as the argument for the substring. Still, this is a good, correct answer.